# Posted comments are rendered in DOM only on refresh (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, rendering

I appreciate anyone's help! I've been stuck on this problem for a while now, and it seems impossible to find a solution.
I am building an app where I have a Notes Component, a User can add notes on a video they are watching. The problem is when I do POST for notes, they get saved on the backend but to see them on a screen I have to refresh. I understand it has something to do with setting state but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am super new to React!

Here is my Notes Component.

```
import React from 'react'
import Note from '../Components/Note'


class NotesContainer extends React.Component {

  state = {
    notes: [],
    note: '',
  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/notes')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({notes: data})
    })
  }

  handleNewNote = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmitNote = e =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    this.postNote()
  }

  postNote = (note) =>{
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const video_id= this.props.video.id 
    const user_id =this.props.user.id
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/notes', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization' : `Bearer ${userToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(({user_id: user_id, video_id: video_id, content: this.state.note}))
      })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data =>{
       console.log(data) 
       this.setState((prevState) =>({
        notes: [...prevState.notes, data.user.notes], 
       }) 
      })
  }

  render(){
    const videoNotes =this.props.video.notes.filter(note => note.user_id === this.props.user.id)
  
    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Write Note:</h4>
        <textarea className="input-group input-group-sm"  type='text' name='note' value={this.state.note} onChange={this.handleNewNote} />
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmitNote}>Add</button>
        </div>
        {videoNotes.map(note => <Note key={note.id} note={note} user={this.props.user} deleteNote={this.deleteNote} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NotesContainer
```

When I'm doing POST, I get back a data object

```
user:
arts: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
bio: null
favorites: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
favvideos: (2) [{…}, {…}]
id: 5
listings: []
location: null
name: "Oli"
notes: (37) [{…}, {…}, ....]
picture: null
username: "oli"
videos: (2) [{…}, {…}]
walls: []
```

Notes is an array of objects like this

```
{notes: Array(47)
0:
content: "hi"
id: 7
user_id: 5
video_id: 1}

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to update the notes is to fetch them again after posting new note. I created updateNotes function which will be called in the componentDidMount and in the postNote

```
class NotesContainer extends React.Component {

  state = {
    notes: [],
    note: '',
  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{
    this.updateNotes()
  }

  updateNotes = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/notes')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({notes: data})
      })
  }

  handleNewNote = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  handleSubmitNote = e =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    this.postNote()
  }

  postNote = (note) =>{
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const video_id= this.props.video.id 
    const user_id =this.props.user.id
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/notes', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization' : `Bearer ${userToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(({user_id: user_id, video_id: video_id, content: this.state.note}))
      })
      .then(resp => this.updateNotes())
  }

  render(){
    const videoNotes =this.props.video.notes.filter(note => note.user_id === this.props.user.id)
  
    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Write Note:</h4>
        <textarea className="input-group input-group-sm"  type='text' name='note' value={this.state.note} onChange={this.handleNewNote} />
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmitNote}>Add</button>
        </div>
        {videoNotes.map(note => <Note key={note.id} note={note} user={this.props.user} deleteNote={this.deleteNote} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It actually did solve the problem! I didn't pay much attention at first and added ```.then(resp => this.updateNotes())``` after updating the state, so it didn't work. But once I removed set state and added that line after the body, it did work! Thanks again!